# PHP: Equal Sides Of An Array

Tags: php

I'm trying to build a function that returns the index of an array where equal sides of the array sum to the same value.

I can get all tests to pass apart from this one:
`$this->assertSame(6,find_even_index([10,-80,10,10,15,35,20]));`

I don't understand why this test has been added by Codewars when it doesn't seem correct? Index 6 is the last item, and doesn't have a right side to equate.

Challenge was taken from Codewars:
https://www.codewars.com/kata/5679aa472b8f57fb8c000047/solutions/php

Code:

```
$numbers = [10,-80,10,10,15,35,20];

echo getEqualSidesIndex($numbers) . PHP_EOL;

function getEqualSidesIndex(array $numbers) : int {
    foreach ($numbers as $key => $value) {
        if ($key < 1) {
            continue; 
        }
    
        $itemsBeforeCurrent = array_slice($numbers, 0, $key - 1);
        $itemsAfterCurrent = array_slice($numbers, $key, count($numbers) - 1);

        if (array_sum($itemsBeforeCurrent) == array_sum($itemsAfterCurrent)) {
            return $key - 1;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Tests:

```
class FindEvenIndexTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testIt() {
      $this->assertSame(3,find_even_index(array(1,2,3,4,3,2,1)));
      $this->assertSame(1,find_even_index([1,100,50,-51,1,1]));
      $this->assertSame(-1,find_even_index([1,2,3,4,5,6]));
      $this->assertSame(3,find_even_index([20,10,30,10,10,15,35]));
      $this->assertSame(0,find_even_index([20,10,-80,10,10,15,35]));
      $this->assertSame(6,find_even_index([10,-80,10,10,15,35,20]));
      $this->assertSame(-1,find_even_index(range(1,100)));
      $this->assertSame(0,find_even_index([0,0,0,0,0]),"Should pick the first index if more cases are valid");
      $this->assertSame(3,find_even_index([-1,-2,-3,-4,-3,-2,-1]));
      $this->assertSame(-1,find_even_index(range(-100,-1)));

    }
}
```

Instructions:

> You are going to be given an array of integers. Your job is to take
> that array and find an index N where the sum of the integers to the
> left of N is equal to the sum of the integers to the right of N. If
> there is no index that would make this happen, return -1.
>
> For example:
>
> Let's say you are given the array {1,2,3,4,3,2,1}: Your function will
> return the index 3, because at the 3rd position of the array, the sum
> of left side of the index ({1,2,3}) and the sum of the right side of
> the index ({3,2,1}) both equal 6.
>
> Let's look at another one. You are given the array {1,100,50,-51,1,1}:
> Your function will return the index 1, because at the 1st position of
> the array, the sum of left side of the index ({1}) and the sum of the
> right side of the index ({50,-51,1,1}) both equal 1.
>
> Last one: You are given the array {20,10,-80,10,10,15,35} At index 0
> the left side is {} The right side is {10,-80,10,10,15,35} They both
> are equal to 0 when added. (Empty arrays are equal to 0 in this
> problem) Index 0 is the place where the left side and right side are
> equal.
>
> Note: Please remember that in most programming/scripting languages the
> index of an array starts at 0.
>
> Input: An integer array of length 0 < arr < 1000. The numbers in the
> array can be any integer positive or negative.
>
> Output: The lowest index N where the side to the left of N is equal to
> the side to the right of N. If you do not find an index that fits
> these rules, then you will return -1.
>
> Note: If you are given an array with multiple answers, return the
> lowest correct index.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider another test for comparison, [20,10,-80,10,10,15,35] should give 0.  But if you apply the logic

> Index 6 is the last item, and doesn't have a right side to equate.

Then the 0th item does not have a left side, so how can you match this.  The way it does match is that the left is considered to be 0, so in the example you say is incorrect - it is expecting all of the previous values to match the '0' on the right hand side.

This function rather than adding up all the values repeatedly, it keeps track of the left and right sums, adjusting them at each item.  This should perform a lot better...

```
function getEqualSidesIndex(array $numbers) : int
{
    // Start with the first number 
    $left = $numbers[0];
    // Start with the all the remaining values minus the first 
    $right = array_sum($numbers) - $left;
    // If the remaining values match 0, then the match is the first item
    if ($right === 0)    {
        return 0;
    }
    // Go from the second value
    foreach (array_slice($numbers, 1) as $key => $value) {
        // Take the new value to be considered away from the remaining sum
        $right -= $value;
        // Check for a match
        if ($left == $right) {
            return $key + 1;
        }
        // Add the value to the new left sum and continue.
        $left += $value;
    }

    return -1;
}
```